# is there a way to check (in console app) if any of the alphanumeric keys that is a-z and 1-9 had been pressed on keyboard?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I know about ( GetLastInputInfo - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx ) - but it reacts on all events mouse too. But that is unpractical because mouse can trigger move from itself any small shock can trigger it.

I also know about GetKeyState and GetAsyncKeyState but these only react to particular keys. Is there a function that can report me what was pressed ?

Also I know about GetKeyboardState ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx ) , but I don't know how to handle PBYTE structure, that is how to check within it if any key was reported. How to display PBYTE on console ?

```
cout << pByte << endl;
```

shows nothing.

Comment: The documentation you linked to for `GetKeyboardState` explains what the `PBYTE` array is and how to interpret it.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: This is an XY question.  Y can't work, you cannot reliably find out *after* the key was pressed in a console mode app.  Use the _getch() function for example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing Win32 code, there's nothing wrong with [`_getch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx). `isalnum` will tell you whether it's an alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WH_KEYBOARD_LL parameter. I believe your HOOKPROC doesn't have to be in a DLL with this parameter choice.